# Firmware bug error message on Arch on Apple

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh, firmware

On Arch Linux on a MacBook Air 5.1 i get the error message

```
DMAR-IR: [Firmware Bug]: ioapic 2 has no mapping iommu,
interrupt remapping will be disabled
```

when booting.  I can't notice any problem, but what is this?
Does it need to be fixed and if so how?

Comment: This seems to be a `grub` issue. Which version of `grub` do you have?

Comment: @C.W., the last line of my grub-install man file says 2.02~beta3.

Answer (score 2):

In general: This feature allows the kernel to replace the remapping tables created by your BIOS.

If it's a system firmware bug, updates to Arch aren't going to fix it. You'd need to update your system firmware (BIOS/UEFI) by flashing. I personally don't recommend that. You should only do this if you really know how to flash your hardware.

The "soft" way is to disable the interrupt remapping in the kernel boot parameters. `intremap=off` disables the kernel interrupt remapping, which might point to your buggy bios or hardware.

First take a look at your config with `cat /proc/cmdline`. Copy it to see changes later on. Now back up your `/etc/default/grub` by copying it to a direction you want. To make the change persistent after a reboot edit `/etc/default/grub` and append your kernel options to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line. In your case it is `intremap=off` (put it into the " "). You can delete the `quiet` if it is in there. Save it and exit.

Now re-generate the grub.cfg file (it is generated with the parameters written in `/etc/default/grub`) with:
`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Reboot your system and the error should be gone. Take a look at your config with `cat /proc/cmdline`, your changes should be visable.

Comment: It seems that the interrupt is disabled anyway.  Is there a reason to do this beyond getting rid of the error message?

Comment: To edit grub is a temporary workaround. The error is caused by a malfunctional firmware which flags to the operating system that it supports interrupt remapping despite the fact that is unable to handle it. So you have to update your motherboards chip-firmware to really get rid of it. BUT you don't need to, especially when your system is stable now.

Answer (score 2):

This error message does not indicate a failure condition, i.e. it will not cause operational problems. Basically, Linux assumes that when there is an IO-APIC and an IOMMU, interrupt remapping must be supported. However, on this hardware it is not supported - the IO-APIC has ID 2 but the IOMMU only matches ID 0. Linux notices this situation, correctly disables interrupt remapping, and prints this notice to dmesg.

Comment: All right.  Doesn't that make `Firmware bug' a bit inappropriate?